# Entity Framework failing to retrieve data due to exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

Here are my two POCOs:

```
[Table("Movie", Schema= "dbo")]
public  class Movie: BaseClass
{
    public string TitleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actor{ get; set; }

}

[Table("Actor", Schema="dbo")]
public class Actor: BaseClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Base class is just a class that has a property int id.

In the database, there's an Movie table and an Actor table with a MovieActor table to act as the many-to-many relationship table. Currently, I'm just interested in getting all the actors for a given movie. But whenever the dbcontext tries to access the information, I keep getting this exception:

```
"InnerException = {"Invalid column name 'Movie_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Movie_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Movie_Id'."}"
```

I searched StackOverflow for a similar issue and they suggested (to the other user) to use a foreign key, so I created an attribute in front of the Actor collection.

```
[ForeignKey("Actor")]
```

And then I get another exception that says:

```
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Actor' on type 
'Movie' is not valid. The foreign key name 
'Actor' was not found on the dependent type     
'Actor'.
The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.
```

Has anybody here run across this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.1 Code-First conventions would create a one-to-many relationship between `Movie` and `Actor`. Since you want a many-to-many relationship you must configure this with Fluent API:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Actor)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(a => {
                a.MapLeftKey("MovieId");  // your PK column name in Movie table
                a.MapRightKey("ActorId"); // your PK column name in Actor table
                a.ToTable("MovieActor");  // your join table name
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/configuring-entity-framework-4-codefirst/) post for more help. I think it will help explain how to do this. You have to scroll down to get to the foreign key portion. It basically says:

> With foreign keys, they can either be exposed in the model or not.
>   When I say “exposed in the model”, it means there is an additional
>   property on the dependent entity that is the value of the principal
>   entity. In the code below, the property PrimaryCategoryCode is an
>   exposed foreign key of Primary Category.
>
> ```
> public string PrimaryCategoryCode { get; set; }
>
> public virtual Category PrimaryCategory { get; set; }
> ```
>
> To indicate this, use the ForeignKey attribute on the PrimaryCategory
>   property as follows:
>
> ```
> public string PrimaryCategoryCode { get; set; }
>
>
> [ForeignKey("PrimaryCategoryCode")]
> public virtual Category PrimaryCategory { get; set; }
> ```

Comment: Ahh I missed the many to many requirement. See Slauma's answer as it is correct.