# MVC3 : HTTPPOST Controller db.SaveChanges() Fails with "Invalid Column Name.."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a create view for invoices that is failing on db.SaveChanges() on the HTTPPOST.  The exception message is {"Invalid column name 'UserDetail_UserId'."}.  In the POST controller it looks like the invoiceitem object I'm trying to add to my InvoiceItems table is populated correctly with the selected username from a dropdownlistfor that gets populated by usernames from my UserDetails table.  "UserId" is the key column in the UserDetails table, but it's not used in the dropdownlist so I'm unclear why any data is trying to be saved to a "UserDetail_UserId" column.  My code below:

**Models:**

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    //Identity Column
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string ProfileUserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public bool InvoicePaid { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string ProfileUserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}

public class ProShotDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLinkToken> UserLinkTokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Controllers:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ProfileUserNames = db.UserDetails.Select(
        c => new
        {
            ProfileUserName = c.ProfileUserName,
            NameAddress = c.FullName + " - " + c.Address
        });
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(InvoiceItem invoiceitem)
    {
        decimal Tax = 1.066m;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            invoiceitem.InvoiceDate = DateTime.Now;
            invoiceitem.SubTotal = invoiceitem.Price*Tax;
            invoiceitem.InvoicePaid = false;

            db.InvoiceItems.Add(invoiceitem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProfileUserNames = db.UserDetails.Select(
        c => new
        {
            ProfileUserName = c.ProfileUserName,
            NameAddress = c.FullName + " - " + c.Address
        });
        return View(invoiceitem);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model Pro_Shot_Portal.Models.InvoiceItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Input Invoice";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Input Invoice:</legend>

    <div class="alert alert-error" style="width:250px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Assigning invoice to wrong user could cause major problems, please triple check before proceeding.
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileUserName, "Attach invoice to user")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProfileUserName, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProfileUserNames, "ProfileUserName", "NameAddress"), "-- Pick Client For Invoice --")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileUserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Invoice Creation", "Index")
</div>
```

From what I can tell the invoiceitem model object properties are filled with the proper data, and the only database change I'm invoking with db.SaveChanges() is "db.InvoiceItems.Add(invoiceitem);".  Can anyone tell me where and why it's trying to access, write or update a column named "UserDetails_UserId".  Maybe I messed something up on the DropdownListFor since that's the only part interacting with the UserDetails table?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like EF is probably looking for a foreign key column on a `User` table somewhere when you probably just have the `User` and `UserDetail` using a 1:1 relationship using the same key. (In other words, I think you're missing the relevant code.)

Comment: The UserId (PK) on UserDetails is the same UserId (PK) on the default membership provider aspnet_Users table.  I got my code to work by adding FK to UserDetails connecting it to aspnet_Users.UserId. Then adding a UserId field to InvoiceItems table and adding a FK to UserDetails.UserId, then changing my selectlist values to UserIds.  I was however trying to avoid attaching any FKs to the default membership tables as I've been told it could cause problems down the road and is bad practice.  Guess I might have to rethink my whole design Here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one-to-many relationship setup, the column name you are seeing with the underscores  in the exception is the relationship default generated.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002389/entity-framework-failing-to-retrieve-data-due-to-exceptions) for more details.

Comment: I'm still not exactly clear on why I need a FK on UserDetails.UserId to aspnet_Users.UserId, however it was assigning FKs that was the problem.  It didn't appear to let me use the [ForeignKey()] attribute on any of my model properties so I set the keys using SSMS which I assume is in effect the same thing.  Some good reading in your link, I'll have to keep learning, thanks for the help.

Comment: When you put "this public virtual ICollection<T>" in your model, you are telling the model builder that there is a relationship.   By convention that means that it expects UserDetail_UserId.  You are free to override this behavior in the model builder using fluent api (check here) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: Ah OK makes a lot more sense now.  I saw the public virtual ICollection<T> properties in other examples but obviously didn't fully understand how MVC3 used it.  Thanks again.